# Does quota count on using outhClient

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

Does the **quota** count if a client ID is using instead of browser key?
Will each user will have different quota limit? 
Is there any alteratives for getting free youtube search and list videos with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Quotas are either user based or project based in most of the Google APIs.  However this is not exactly the same with the YouTube API.  The YouTube API is quota cost based.  That means that depending upon which method you are calling the quota can be different.  The quota is set against your project not just the client.  So if you have a project with six client ids and you have applications using all six client ids they are sharing the quota for the project.

The [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) is useful for estimating your quota usage.

> This tool lets you estimate the quota cost for an API query. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.
>
> To use the tool, select the appropriate resource, method, and part parameter values for your request, and the approximate quota cost will display in the table. Please remember that quota costs can change without warning, and the values shown here may not be exact.